# Calling vertices in Igraph

Tags: r, igraph

This question pertains to the calling of vertices in Igraph.

Lets say we have a directed graph

> `g<-graph(c(1:10),directed=T)`

and i want to find the vertices pointing to vertex 2.

Lets say you want to find the vertices pointed "to" vertex 1.

Why won't using the "to" condition work

> `V(g)[to(1)]`

but rather this?

> `V(g)[nei(1,"to")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to` works only with edge sequences; e.g., `E(g)[to(1)]` gives you all the edges that point to vertex 1. IMHO this is quite logical since vertices do not "point" anywhere (the edges do) so it does not make sense to use `from` or `to`.

Also, the "official" way of using `nei` is `nei(1, "out")` and not `nei(1, "to")` although it could be the case that `"to"` works as well. You can use `outnei(1)` as well.

*Disclaimer:* I am one of the authors of igraph although I did not write the R interface so there might be a better reason than the one I explained above.

Comment: The outnei(1) function is not in the R package of igraph

Comment: Hmm, seems to be a bug for me. This works: `V(g)[outnei(1, mode="out")]` but this does not: `V(g)[outnei(1)]`. I will create a bug report for this.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me?

```
> g<-graph(c(1:10),directed=T)
> V(g)[to(1)]
Vertex sequence:
[1] 2
> V(g)[nei(1,"to")]
Vertex sequence:
[1] 2
```

Personally I like working with edgelists. Alternatively you could do it like this:

```
# Get edgelist:
E <- get.edgelist(g)

# To 1 in directed graph:
E[E[,2]==1,1]

# Connected to 1 in undirected graph:
c(E[E[,2]==1,1],E[E[,1]==1,2])
```